# Uncaught exception java.lang.stackoverflowerror

Tags: jmeter-3.2

I am getting the error "Uncaught Exception java.lang.stack overflow error null in Jmeter while performing only one thread.  Initially, all requests passed, when I try to click on 11th request to see the HTML response type it starts throwing errors.  Since that page contains more  images with search functionality

Comment: We need more informations, configuration and also code to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the Java VM with a larger stack size by applying a flag like `-Xss1024k`. From what I found, the default is `1024k` (1 MB).

For example:

```
$ java -Xss2048k -jar myfile.jar
```

or

```
$ java -Xss256m -jar myfile.jar
```

The alternative is to optimize your code. However,

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>
> - [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)